# Can't update avatar img without page refresh (rails, jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Apologies in advance. I'm new to using async calls and I've been struggling with this for a while now. I'd like to update a user avatar image without having to refresh the page after the image has been saved to the user model.

```
<form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_<%= current_user.id %>" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="/users/<%= current_user.id %>" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
  <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" 
    type="hidden">
  <div id="upload-wrap">
    <input id="user-avatar" type="file" name="user[avatar]" />
  </div>
</form>

// controller 
def update
  @user = current_user
  user_params = params.require(:user).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :avatar)
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params) && params[:user].include?('avatar')
    render json: @user.avatar.to_json
  end
end
```

Currently, the image DOES save, and I'm just spitting out the image link to the screen as json. How do I send this information back to the view so that I can render it without a full page refresh?

p.s. - tried to do this with $.ajax, but the img file was absent from the params in the controller.

Here is what I get back from the controller:

```
{
  "url": 
    "https://gametiks.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/4/turkey.jpg",
  "square": {
    "url": "https://gametiks.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/avatar/4/square_turkey.jpg"
  }
}
```

My original implementation with ajax:

```
var avatarForm = document.getElementById(`edit_user_${userId}`);

$(avatarForm).change(function() {
  avatarForm.submit();
});

$(avatarForm).submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: "POST"
  });
});
```

The dom element that gets updated:

```
<%= @user.avatar.present? ? image_tag(@user.avatar.url(:square), id: 'avatar-img') : image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/gametiks/users/avatars/Gametiks_Gamercard.jpg") %>
```

Using form_for @user without specifying 'remote', I get this as parameters (missing file):

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"gtFR2C8zlmQhIDqNcecSp02kW+OPf9FehMDKW9KpQ79IsSwuTIXE8wjSHFTXy+oQP2n3b9Xpo5T/vg5+2+imLA==", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"4"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: Can you show us the javascript you tried and what the params from the controller are (we don't know what your `avatar.to_json` looks like). Also where is the image tag you are trying update in the HTML? By 'the img file was absent' do you mean the url? wouldn't think you'd want to send the entire file, just a url back to set as the source on the `img` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread your question @Jason, hence I'm deleting my answer. I thought you already had the ajax upload going on. It's actually quite a bit more complex to upload through ajax. You'll need either to use something like remotipart, https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart, or build yourself the upload with jquery fileupload, or  Dropzone.js, and then save (or pass the `file` to  whatever gem you're using to upload right now) the uploaded file on your controller.

Comment: ok, I'll probably leave it as-is for now. I used a redirect to just re-render the page after upload. I tried to use remotipart at one point. But it didn't seem to work with Rails 5. I may try your other suggestions at a later time.